# Excel vba Offset issue

Tags: excel, vba, offset

After running the following piece of code I would expect the cell to be D4 but it's E5. Why? Am I missing something?

```
***Sub off()
Dim testRange As Range
Set testRange = Range("b2:i10")
MsgBox ("Here: " & testRange.Range("B2").Offset(2, 2))
End Sub***
```

Answer (score 3):

`testRange.Range("B2")` refers to the second row and second column of the `testRange` range, not of the containing worksheet. In this case, that would be C3. You then offset two columns and two rows from there, which is E5.

Answer (score 1):

You have set testRange equal to range b2:i10. Thus, testRange.Range("B2") is the second column and second row in your test range B2:I10, or C3. If you offset C3 2 rows and 2 col, you land on E5. If the code is changed to {Range("B2").Offset(2, 2).Activate}, then D5 will be activated. I am not sure what the rest of your code is intended for, but this should answer your question I hope!

Comment: I see now that Rory already answered this correctly.